# Is the expression "question difficile à répondre" correct?

Tags: prépositions, verbes, infinitif

When we say : "une pomme difficile à manger" it comes from "manger une pomme".
But when we say "une question difficile à répondre" it comes from "répondre **à** une question".

It seems to me this "à" is lost and going backwards would produce : "répondre une question".

Is the expression correct or is my concern valid?

Comment: Difficile de répondre à cette question !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I would write :

> Question difficile à poser
>
> Je n'ai rien à répondre
>
> Il m'est difficile de répondre

I would definitely avoid *question difficile à répondre* which hurts my ears by using this established form:

> Question à laquelle il est difficile de répondre

or simply the shorter:

> Question difficile

Comment: J'ajouterai même, "Difficile d'y répondre !"

Comment: @Kii oui, mais pas « Question difficile d'y répondre ! » ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Pourriez-vous m'expliquer pourquoi vous n'utiliserez pas "question difficile à repondre"?

Comment: But Why does it hurt! Because it hurts mine too.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon Because *on ne répond pas une question*.

Answer (score 1):

En effet, on a compris intuitivement que dans un cas on a un verbe utilisé de manière *transitive directe* (*manger* + objet direct), et dans l'autre, en *transitif indirect* ([*répondre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9pondre) à + *une question* ; par opposition à *ne rien répondre, répondre oui, non* : l'emploi transitif direct). La nuance est importante avec l'*infinitif complément d'adjectifs* tels que *facile/difficile*, où l'emploi avec la préposition *à* s'est spécialisé au milieu du 19<sup>e</sup> aux cas où le nom ou le pronom auquel réfère l'adjectif sert d'**objet direct** à l'infinitif (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §915 a 2°, n. H1) ; ce qui est le cas de la pomme que l'on mange difficilement, mais pas de la question *à laquelle* on répond (par opposition à la question que l'on *poserait*).<sup>1</sup> Conséquemment « *une question difficile à répondre* » semble à tout le moins inusité aujourd'hui et l'on a d'[autres solutions](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17619) plus usuelles.

[ Your observation about how the complement is introduced for such and such a verb was very astute. Saying "une question difficile à répondre" is at least unusual. In such cases, usage is adjective-specific, but it also varies according to how the verb is leveraged; with *facile/difficile*, using *à + inf.* is nowadays seemingly restricted to verbs calling for a *direct object complement*, which is not the case here with *répondre à*, but is indeed the case with *manger (une pomme)* and *poser (une question)*. ]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> L'usage varie ainsi selon les adjectifs, et incidemment selon les verbes. Comme on l'a dit, le tour avec *à* était fréquent avant le 19<sup>e</sup> avec *facile/difficile* sur le modèle *apte à/enclin à* :</sub>

> <sub>*De véritables Gens de bien qui sont faciles à recevoir les impressions
>   qu'on veut leur donner* (Molière)
>  *Le premier piège qui m'a rendu
>   longtems si facile à tomber dans tous les autres* (Rousseau)
>
>   *Il étoit très difficile à promettre et s'engager dans les plus petites choses* (Bernardin de St. Pierre)</sub>

<sub>« *Cet homme est facile à être convaincu* » est sorti d'usage. On ne peut toujours remplacer la construction par un complément adverbial ; l'infinitif peut être plutôt sujet d'une attribution (« *convaincre cet homme est facile* »), et dans ce cas on ne pourra lui substituer le pronom *y* (« *cet homme y est facile »(x)). Au *LBU14* on regroupe les usages selon la nature du rapport entre le nom et l'infinitif [(Le nom ou le pronom (1) sert de sujet à l'infinitif, (2) sert d'objet direct à l'inf. (contra *répondre à* ici), (3) ne sert ni de sujet ni d'objet, et on donne par exemple « Il m'est reconnaissant de ne pas me prévaloir de cette coïncidence » (Gracq), ou finalement selon que (4) l'infinitif n'a ni sujet exprimé ni sujet possible)], et on traite de cas particuliers. On critique *Robert* quand il critique un « *objet facile à se procurer* » (vs. « *qu'il est facile de se procurer* ») ; on dit que la première construction est fort répandue et bien présente chez les classiques, comme en témoigne l'[ancien dictionnaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/difficile) de l'Académie (1694) avec « *un auteur difficile à entendre* », « *un cheval difficile à ferrer* » etc. Il y a bien des nuances dans les différents tours attestés (voir au *LBU*, qu'on paraphrase et d'où on puise les exemples, pour les détails).</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is correct. In this case, the *à* is not associated to the verb, that is it's not a reorganization of a different construction already containing the word. Rather that preposition is associated specifically with the the adjectival construction, it's the same principle that the preposition *de* in the expression *il est difficile de* never changes.

Comment: Do you really use this in Quebec? I found more [occurrences](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22difficile+%C3%A0+r%C3%A9pondre%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr&gws_rd=cr) stating the incorrectness of this phrasing than actual uses of the phrasing.

Comment: Je pense comprendre finalement que vous vouliez dire un _syntagme adjectival_ invariable comme la locution figée _à même de_ ? Merci.

Answer (score -3):

Le *problème* vient de la préposition *à* .

> Question difficile de répondre : **incorrect**, car le verbe répondre n'est pas transitif.

le *à* devient le pronom relatif *à laquelle* en inversant la construction,
avec une proposition relative complète, comme proposée par jlliagre:

> Question à laquelle il est difficile de répondre.

En omettant il est, on peut simplifier ainsi:

> Question à laquelle difficile de répondre.

Si l'on veut utiliser un synonyme dérivé d'un verbe transitif, on peut employer:

> Question difficile à solutionner.

Comment: _Question à laquelle difficile de répondre_. On ne peut omettre _il est_ ici.